# knitr - strange behaviour for digits

Tags: r, knitr

I ran into some trouble concerning the number of digits printed in knitr.
The number does not correspond to the settings [`options('digits')`].
I know that it was an issue with that about a year ago but has been resolved (https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/120).

````
```{r}
packageVersion("knitr")
options("digits")
a <- 100.101
a
as.character(a)
options(digits=4)
a
options(digits=10)
a
```
````

This is what I get (the same on two different machines): http://rpubs.com/markheckmann/6715 .
[image]
Something is going wrong here and I do not have a clue. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you *expecting*?

Comment: At least for the output of the first `a` I expected `100.101` just like in the R console. But maybe I do indeed misunderstand the `digits` parameter. In the docu is says: `digits:
controls the number of digits to print when printing numeric values.`So I would expect `100.101` not `100.1` (as `digits` is 4) Do I get that wrong?

Comment: Or am I wrong to assume that `digits` refers to the decimal places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `options(digits=10)` is doing what you *exepct*. Perhaps you meant

```
sprintf( "%.10f",101.101)
# [1] "101.1010000000"
```

Comment: I expected the number `100.101` not to get truncated to `100.1` when the number of significant digits is set to `4`. But maybe I get the term "significant digits" wrong...

Comment: All right. I figured that I completely misunderstood the term `significant digits`. Funny that I never noticed this behaviour throughout the years. Seems that the default `digits=7` was sufficient in most cases. But hacking in the following numbers made things clear now: `123456.7` `123456.78`

Comment: @MarkHeckmann glad you found out. Sorry not to have replied sooner, I was offline for a bit!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a knitr issue; it's just how R displays digits.  Try your code on its own, without knitting.

```
a <- 100.101
a
#[1] 100.101
as.character(a)
#[1] "100.101"
options(digits=4)
a
#[1] 100.1
options(digits=10)
a
[1] 100.101
```

`print` doesn't pad numbers with zeroes to make up the width; for that you need `format`.

```
format(a, nsmall = 10)
#[1] "100.1010000000"
```